# Building raster qgis-plugin on Linux?

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-plugins, linux

I am trying to build a qgis-plugin for a raster format (say .rst extension), I am able to build it on windows but facing issues on Linux.

I am running "make plugin" command from frtms/rst folder, it runs fine but don't creates a gdal_RST.so file. Prior to this I already ran configure and make command.

Am I missing anything. This is how plugin tag looks like in my GNUmakefile:

```
$(PLUGIN_SO):   $(OBJ)

        $(LD_SHARED) $(LNK_FLAGS) $(OBJ) $(CONFIG_LIBS) $(EXTRA_LIBS) \
            -o $(PLUGIN_SO)
```